# python regex Получить буквы, идущее после любого символа, который не буква

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно получить буквы с конца слова, которое идет после любого символа, который не является буквой:

```
test/my_word => world
test/my+another_word-mp => mp
report/-r=post?e => e
```

Comment: `re.sub(r".*?([a-z]+)$", r"\1", my_string, flags=re.I)` ?

Comment: Буквы только латинские строчные?

Answer (score 1):

Этого вполне хватит (если гарантированно есть хотя бы одна небуква):

```
[a-z]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться методом исключения для символов, которые обозначают не букву:

```
    re.sub(r"[^a-z]*?([a-z]+)$", r"\1", my_string, re.I)
```